.NET MAUI - iOS App Crash - Help on understand the reason
I'm working on an iOS application built using MAUI. The application is being tested via TestFlight. The crash occurs when the app is put in the background and not used for a few days, after which the app is brought back to the foreground and after having performed a certain action it crashes (the same action is performed without sending it in the background for a few days, does not produce any crashes).
This is the crash log, and it should already be full of symbols, but I can't "read" it.
Incident Identifier: C5F5567F-CA66-4FBD-B8D2-60D024DF17F4
Distributor ID:      com.apple.TestFlight
Hardware Model:      iPhone14,5
Process:             iFit [15954]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2393AF51-F9F5-4C7F-878E-F50CFFA18A4D/iFit.app/iFit
Identifier:          ifit.it.k2.dev
Version:             2.1 (49)
AppStoreTools:       15E204
AppVariant:          1:iPhone14,5:17.4
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           ifit.it.k2.dev [7138]

Date/Time:           2024-05-06 14:55:17.1098 +0200
Launch Time:         2024-05-06 14:54:09.1426 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 17.4.1 (21E236)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    3.50.04
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4328554496
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                   102008000-105a14000 [ 58.0M] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /var/containers/Bundle/Application/2393AF51-F9F5-4C7F-878E-F50CFFA18A4D/iFit.app/iFit
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: iFit [15954]

Triggered by Thread:  0


Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a42974 __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c50ec pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1717)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001a1493b80 abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
3   iFit                            0x0000000105a56448 sigabrt_signal_handler.cold.1 + 48 (mini-posix.c:226)
4   iFit                            0x00000001059d8d00 sigabrt_signal_handler + 168 (mini-posix.c:224)
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001f540f834 _sigtramp + 56 (sigtramp.c:116)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c50ec pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1717)
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001a1493b80 abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
8   iFit                            0x00000001056f2584 xamarin_unhandled_exception_handler + 60 (runtime.m:1126)
9   iFit                            0x00000001058bcf00 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 132 (exception.c:1219)
10  iFit                            0x00000001059b0c54 mono_jit_exec_internal + 56 (driver.c:1370)
11  iFit                            0x00000001059b0c54 mono_jit_exec + 396 (driver.c:1310)
12  iFit                            0x00000001056fac88 xamarin_main + 972 (monotouch-main.m:490)
13  iFit                            0x0000000105a1757c main + 72 (main.arm64.mm:317)
14  dyld                            0x00000001bca32d84 start + 2240 (dyldMain.cpp:1298)

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a3a49c __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0590 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   iFit                            0x000000010599d2e4 mono_os_cond_wait + 8 (mono-os-mutex.h:219)
3   iFit                            0x000000010599d2e4 get_work + 240 (sgen-thread-pool.c:167)
4   iFit                            0x000000010599d2e4 thread_func + 468 (sgen-thread-pool.c:198)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c1a90 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:927)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fcc thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a39a74 semaphore_wait_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   iFit                            0x00000001059305ac mono_os_sem_wait + 12 (mono-os-semaphore.h:85)
2   iFit                            0x00000001059305ac mono_coop_sem_wait + 32 (mono-coop-semaphore.h:41)
3   iFit                            0x00000001059305ac finalizer_thread + 328 (gc.c:891)
4   iFit                            0x000000010590f6a8 start_wrapper_internal + 328 (threads.c:1202)
5   iFit                            0x000000010590f530 start_wrapper + 44 (threads.c:1264)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c1a90 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:927)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fcc thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a39af8 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a39890 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a397a8 mach_msg_overwrite + 436 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a395e8 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019951401c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199511f04 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199511968 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001983a04a8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001983ca4e8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
9   UIKitCore                       0x000000019b8e7ac8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 420 (UIEventFetcher.m:1201)
10  Foundation                      0x0000000198411a9c __NSThread__start__ + 732 (NSThread.m:991)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c1a90 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:927)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fcc thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a3a49c __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0590 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   iFit                            0x00000001059546d0 mono_os_cond_timedwait + 168 (mono-os-mutex.c:75)
3   iFit                            0x00000001059585e0 mono_coop_cond_timedwait + 32 (mono-coop-mutex.h:103)
4   iFit                            0x00000001059585e0 mono_lifo_semaphore_timed_wait + 208 (lifo-semaphore.c:48)
5   iFit                            0x0000000102596ab0 wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_LowLevelLifoSemaphore_TimedWaitInternal_intptr_int + 128
6   iFit                            0x0000000104c291a8 corlib_System_Threading_LowLevelLifoSemaphore_WaitForSignal_int + 92
7   iFit                            0x0000000104c2664c corlib_System_Threading_Thread_StartCallback + 256
8   iFit                            0x00000001059abbc0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1320 (mini-runtime.c:3613)
9   iFit                            0x00000001058fb174 do_runtime_invoke + 60 (object.c:2399)
10  iFit                            0x00000001058fb174 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 148 (object.c:2567)
11  iFit                            0x000000010590f7a0 start_wrapper_internal + 576 (threads.c:1213)
12  iFit                            0x000000010590f530 start_wrapper + 44 (threads.c:1264)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c1a90 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:927)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fcc thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a3a49c __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c05bc _pthread_cond_wait + 1272 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   iFit                            0x0000000105746948 SystemNative_LowLevelMonitor_TimedWait + 104 (pal_threading.c:177)
3   iFit                            0x00000001026db9bc wrapper_managed_to_native_Interop_Sys__LowLevelMonitor_TimedWaitg____PInvoke_67_0_intptr_int + 140
4   iFit                            0x0000000104c33400 corlib_System_Threading_LowLevelMonitor_WaitCore_int + 52
5   iFit                            0x0000000104c4cbf8 corlib_System_Threading_WaitSubsystem_WaitableObject_Wait_Locked_System_Threading_WaitSubsystem_ThreadWaitInfo_int_bool_bool_System_Threading_WaitSubsystem_LockHolder_ + 284
6   iFit                            0x0000000104c2664c corlib_System_Threading_Thread_StartCallback + 256
7   iFit                            0x00000001059abbc0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1320 (mini-runtime.c:3613)
8   iFit                            0x00000001058fb174 do_runtime_invoke + 60 (object.c:2399)
9   iFit                            0x00000001058fb174 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 148 (object.c:2567)
10  iFit                            0x000000010590f7a0 start_wrapper_internal + 576 (threads.c:1213)
11  iFit                            0x000000010590f530 start_wrapper + 44 (threads.c:1264)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c1a90 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:927)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fcc thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a3a49c __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0590 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   iFit                            0x00000001059546d0 mono_os_cond_timedwait + 168 (mono-os-mutex.c:75)
3   iFit                            0x00000001059585e0 mono_coop_cond_timedwait + 32 (mono-coop-mutex.h:103)
4   iFit                            0x00000001059585e0 mono_lifo_semaphore_timed_wait + 208 (lifo-semaphore.c:48)
5   iFit                            0x0000000102596ab0 wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_LowLevelLifoSemaphore_TimedWaitInternal_intptr_int + 128
6   iFit                            0x0000000104c291a8 corlib_System_Threading_LowLevelLifoSemaphore_WaitForSignal_int + 92
7   iFit                            0x0000000104c2664c corlib_System_Threading_Thread_StartCallback + 256
8   iFit                            0x00000001059abbc0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1320 (mini-runtime.c:3613)
9   iFit                            0x00000001058fb174 do_runtime_invoke + 60 (object.c:2399)
10  iFit                            0x00000001058fb174 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 148 (object.c:2567)
11  iFit                            0x000000010590f7a0 start_wrapper_internal + 576 (threads.c:1213)
12  iFit                            0x000000010590f530 start_wrapper + 44 (threads.c:1264)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c1a90 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:927)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fcc thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a3a49c __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c05bc _pthread_cond_wait + 1272 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   iFit                            0x0000000105746948 SystemNative_LowLevelMonitor_TimedWait + 104 (pal_threading.c:177)
3   iFit                            0x00000001026db9bc wrapper_managed_to_native_Interop_Sys__LowLevelMonitor_TimedWaitg____PInvoke_67_0_intptr_int + 140
4   iFit                            0x0000000104c33400 corlib_System_Threading_LowLevelMonitor_WaitCore_int + 52
5   iFit                            0x0000000104c4cbf8 corlib_System_Threading_WaitSubsystem_WaitableObject_Wait_Locked_System_Threading_WaitSubsystem_ThreadWaitInfo_int_bool_bool_System_Threading_WaitSubsystem_LockHolder_ + 284
6   iFit                            0x00000001059abbc0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1320 (mini-runtime.c:3613)
7   iFit                            0x00000001058fb174 do_runtime_invoke + 60 (object.c:2399)
8   iFit                            0x00000001058fb174 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 148 (object.c:2567)
9   iFit                            0x000000010590f7a0 start_wrapper_internal + 576 (threads.c:1213)
10  iFit                            0x000000010590f530 start_wrapper + 44 (threads.c:1264)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c1a90 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:927)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fcc thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fb8 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fb8 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fb8 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fb8 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 12 name:
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a39af8 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a39890 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a397a8 mach_msg_overwrite + 436 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a395e8 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019951401c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199511f04 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000199511968 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   CFNetwork                       0x000000019a870c48 +[__CFN_CoreSchedulingSetRunnable _run:] + 384 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1479)
8   Foundation                      0x0000000198411a9c __NSThread__start__ + 732 (NSThread.m:991)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c1a90 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:927)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fcc thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 13 name:
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e1a3a49c __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0590 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   iFit                            0x00000001059546d0 mono_os_cond_timedwait + 168 (mono-os-mutex.c:75)
3   iFit                            0x00000001059585e0 mono_coop_cond_timedwait + 32 (mono-coop-mutex.h:103)
4   iFit                            0x00000001059585e0 mono_lifo_semaphore_timed_wait + 208 (lifo-semaphore.c:48)
5   iFit                            0x0000000102596ab0 wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_LowLevelLifoSemaphore_TimedWaitInternal_intptr_int + 128
6   iFit                            0x0000000104c291a8 corlib_System_Threading_LowLevelLifoSemaphore_WaitForSignal_int + 92
7   iFit                            0x0000000104c2664c corlib_System_Threading_Thread_StartCallback + 256
8   iFit                            0x00000001059abbc0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1320 (mini-runtime.c:3613)
9   iFit                            0x00000001058fb174 do_runtime_invoke + 60 (object.c:2399)
10  iFit                            0x00000001058fb174 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 148 (object.c:2567)
11  iFit                            0x000000010590f7a0 start_wrapper_internal + 576 (threads.c:1213)
12  iFit                            0x000000010590f530 start_wrapper + 44 (threads.c:1264)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c1a90 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:927)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fcc thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 14 name:
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fb8 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fb8 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fb8 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fb8 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f54c0fb8 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0xffffffff97f48316   x5: 0x0000000000000018   x6: 0x000000016ddf6d90   x7: 0x000000016ddf6480
    x8: 0xcc86eabc32b0324f   x9: 0xcc86eabdc8174d4f  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000016ddf64f0
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000102558128  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001faa77f00  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000103  x21: 0x00000001faa77fe0  x22: 0x0000000107843600  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x0000000302ec1440  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x000000016ddf7c85
   x28: 0x00000003038c4240   fp: 0x000000016ddf6da0   lr: 0x00000001f54c50ec
    sp: 0x000000016ddf6d80   pc: 0x00000001e1a42974 cpsr: 0x40001000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault


Binary Images:
        0x102008000 -         0x105d6ffff iFit arm64  <97e9170fdc2a3a4891e812725fe479d2> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2393AF51-F9F5-4C7F-878E-F50CFFA18A4D/iFit.app/iFit
        0x106848000 -         0x106dabfff libSkiaSharp arm64  <649ef09dce4e3167a06b4c7ae3801717> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2393AF51-F9F5-4C7F-878E-F50CFFA18A4D/iFit.app/Frameworks/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp
        0x10b7b4000 -         0x10b7bffff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e  <19bc6b58cbf535a583a5fc742451547d> /private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
        0x198375000 -         0x198f00fff Foundation arm64e  <d92e19c162993e948614c505d5abccdb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
        0x1994de000 -         0x199a0bfff CoreFoundation arm64e  <3a5f992ad1cd312ebd2ef7c66343a417> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
        0x19a616000 -         0x19a9f2fff CFNetwork arm64e  <a0da81af67733a72a9a5264f31047a16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
        0x19b75a000 -         0x19d26afff UIKitCore arm64e  <7bf01cfc23f1326aafd8ad967ffece28> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
        0x1a141e000 -         0x1a149bfff libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <3b5201c515d0335fa91d0c63e1f6c6dc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
        0x1bca2d000 -         0x1bcab9be3 dyld arm64e  <7be2b7573b3d3e918cb774f3887660c7> /usr/lib/dyld
        0x1e1a38000 -         0x1e1a71fef libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <db493af363b132209dd8dd4f86bddfc8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
        0x1f540a000 -         0x1f5410feb libsystem_platform.dylib arm64e  <e29c0ee481183a92bff81c343f8885ad> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
        0x1f54bf000 -         0x1f54cbfff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <a70c0def058c3cb09ec1453aa7f39df9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

EOF

I have the impression that it is something linked to a possible writing of data from memory, and then to an attempt to access them by some component, but not strictly linked to the written code. I would have expected to see some reference within this log.

About Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6, you can see this post: Xcode crash when upload to app connect.
